# Como pegar imagem da camera em base64 (utilizando o phonegap) e enviar para servidor via JSON com AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova

Estou pegando a var `imgEnviar`, que recebe o `base64` que vem da câmera, e inserindo no JSON e enviar para o servidor com $http com AngularJS. Quero saber se realmente é possível ou se tem uma forma melhor de fazer isso, pois preciso enviar a imagem da câmera junto com os dados do formulário.

Parte da câmera com plugin Cordova

```
var imgEnviar;
function capturarImagem(){
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
                    {
                        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
                    }
                );
            }

            function onSuccess(imageURL) {
                var image = document.getElementById('htmlImagem');
                image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURL;
                //var imgEnviar = JSON.stringify(imageURL); 
                imgEnviar = image.src;
            }

            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Erro: ' + message);
            }
pate do agularJS


app.controller('formularioChamado', function($scope, $http) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});

 $scope.enviarForm = function(chamado){


  $http({
    url: 'https://modulosamu.herokuapp.com/chamado/store',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {

      descricao: $scope.chamado.descricao,
      img: imgEnviar,
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,


    },
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'

    }
  }).
  success(function (data) {
    $scope.success = true;
    alert(data);
    $scope.user = {};
  }).
  error(function (data) {
    $scope.error = true;

  }); 

}

});
```

Comment: Usa um service que fiz em AngularJS
https://github.com/marangonijunior/bananaJs/blob/master/bananaJs.js Bem tranquilo pra acessar alguns plugins.
*Precisa ter instalado os plugins ok. Sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra fazer sim, mas vc vai ter que configurar algumas coisas mais tipo:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
        quality         : 25, 
        allowEdit       : false,
        //destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
        targetWidth     : 200,
        targetHeight    : 200,
        sourceType      : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        encodingType    : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    });
```

Quality quanto menor melhor para enviar, width/height mesma ideia, depois é só enviar como string e gravar no banco.

Comment: Valeu, mas do jeito que eu fiz acima já funciona, o meu problema era o servidor que não estava conseguindo guarda os dados em base64 devido o tamanho do arquivo. Devido a isso colocamos o campo do banco em mediumBlob pra aumentar o tamanho do campo no Banco de dados, antes o campo era somente blob.